# How do I sftp to a server if the username contains @ symbol

Tags: ssh, users, sftp

I have to sftp to a server to a specific port but the username contains the @ symbol.

suppose the user is "user@example.com"
and the ftp server is just "example.com"

I will end with

```
sftp -oPort=8777 user@example.com@example.com
```

what will obviously not work, as I have tested.

What kind of amateur creates a username with @? Ok, my boss did.

How do I solve that?

Comment: Try escaping the "commercial at" like so `sftp -oPort:8777 user\@domain.com@domain.com`

Comment: If you remove the username portion and just leave the domain, does it prompt you for the username once you've entered the command?

Comment: @ladaghini - this is to be used inside a script... no prompt available. Ok, I know the implications of having username and password in a script, but this username has a limited area. It has to be sftp because this server just generates usernames for sftp.

Comment: @Tim ... escaping it is not helping.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Pass the user name through the `-o User` option, or through the equivalent `User` directive in the client configuration file (`~/.ssh/config`).

```
sftp -o Port=8777 -o User=user@example.com example.com
```

This applies to `ssh`, `scp` and `sshfs` as well. Using the configuration file instead of `-o` options has the advantage of also working with tools that call `ssh` and don't let you easily pass command line options if at all.

Comment: This username has not ssh access, just sftp.

Comment: @DigitalRobot s/ssh/sftp/

Comment: @DigitalRobot This works for both `ssh` and `sftp` (and `scp` too).

Comment: Go on. What should we do if the passwd also contain '@' or '/'

Comment: @ShichengGuo ??? There's no problem with `@` or `/` in the password. You just type them. SSH doesn't even allow any way to pass the password on the command line option or in a configuration file.

Comment: I don't know why but in my case replacing Port:8777 to Port=8777 worked             sftp -o Port=8777 -o User=user@example.com example.com

Comment: @farness Indeed, `Port:` was from the question but it should be `Port=`.

Answer (score 5):

```
sftp -o Port=8777 'user@domain.com'@domain.com
```

This would also work, although its really quite poor form for them to provision users with this type of name.

Comment: The quotes do not change anything since the characters between them are not special to the shell. The `sftp` command receives the same arguments as in the question, and the question states that this doesn't work.

Comment: That's no different to the original suggestion in the question. All you've done is provide a pair of quotes that the shell strips before passing the string on to the `sftp` command

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `@` ("commercial at") with `+` ("plus sign)" could be acceptable on some SFTP servers:

```
sftp -oPort=8777 user+example.com@example.com
```