# SSH works but not SFTP

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, docker, sftp

I am working on a project for a client from which we are using multiple docker containers on a host machine. I need to copy some files from my computer to the host machine, but when using an SFTP-client (cyberduck) I cannot connect to the server.

The address has multiple `@` in it, which might be why I am not able to connect?

The SSH-command is like this:

`ssh username@name@identifier@domain.com`

I've tried putting the username in the SFTP client like `username@name@identifier` and server as `domain.com`, but I still cannot connect.

Is this even possible to do? Can I check through the terminal of the host if I am able to sftp into the host?

#### Log when SSH:ing into the server

```
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to domain.com:22 as 'username@name@identifier'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve12345-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-******
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: ****-poly***@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: *****-poly***@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ***********
debug1: Host 'domain.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:16
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:******* /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
username@name@identifier@domain.com's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to domain.com ([12.345.678.9101]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8

This session is being recorded
Using username "other_username".
LEGAL NOTICE
------------
This is a PRIVATE computer system.
All unauthorized use or unauthorized access is prohibited
according to local laws and may lead to prosecution.
```

#### Log when SFTP:ing from terminal

```
Authenticated to Authenticated to domain.com ([12.345.678.9101]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
subsystem request failed on channel 0
Connection closed
```

Comment: "Cannot connect" is kind of vague. Can you show us the logs on either end? Can you run `ssh -v` and/or add debug instructions to the ssh server on the receiving end? Please update this question with the relevant log information.

Comment: Try this: `'username@name'@'identifier'`...

Comment: Also, cyberduck is a windows program. Consider the possibility that the problem lies on the client end - especially if, as you claim, ssh itself works.

Comment: I have updated the post with a log when SSH:ing into the server. I am using the mac version of the cyberduck client.

Comment: Relating/similar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97003/117549

Comment: Updated thread with `sftp` log (doesn't work from the terminal either)

Comment: Excellent, we're already a step further. **`subsystem request failed on channel 0`** The server couldn't load the subsystem. Now check the logs from the server end, preferably with debug enabled.

Comment: Have you tried `scp`? I believe that sftp relies on the server running an ftpd daemon, but scp only needs sshd.

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify the old `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I added the following and restarted the machine:

```
# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: just restart or reload the sshd service, `sudo service ssh reload` instead of rebooting system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up adding the Subsystem line to /etc/ssh/sshd_config, then reloading sshd service.  That solved it for me.  My setup is a vanilla installation of Xubuntu 20.04